# Android Java: Toast appear only when my activity change

Tags: java, android, button, toast

I'm trying to use a Toast in a onClick, but the toast only appear when I'm on the next activity...

For exemple I'm in the PhotoActivity and when I clicked on a button I use startActivity to go to the MainActivity:

```
findViewById(R.id.back).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Hello you!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainPhoto.this, MainFragmentControl.class);
            bundle.putString("lastActivity", "MainPhoto");
            intent.putExtra("bundle", bundle);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

But when I try this, I saw the toast in the MainActivity and not in the PhotoActivity...

If anyone can help me! :D

Comment: Your Toast does not appears on the other Activity, what happens it that the change to other Activity is fast, and then, the Toast and the startActivity happens almost at the same time, and it APPEARS to be shown in the second Activity.

Comment: Ok, but when I go back in the MainActivity I launch a big treatment, and the screen freeze, so I want to have the toast before the freeze then users know why it's too long to back to the activity.

Comment: Don't do your 'big treatment' on the UI thread.

Comment: The idea of a screen freezing gives me the creeps. You should use a ProgressDialog to show your users that something big is happening. Or put that big thing happening on a separate thread, so it doesn't blocks your app.

Comment: How can I do this treatment in other thread?

Comment: Google it...is not something that can be explained here.

Comment: Ok, but the biggest of my treatment is to convert my Object to a Json so I use Jackson. I've try to use it in AsyncTask but that change nothing...